Teams plugin for real-time voice translation
I am looking to build a Microsoft Teams plugin for real-time voice translation. The requirements are:

The plugin should access the audio stream of a Microsoft Teams meeting.

Provide live transcription (speech to text) of the audio stream in the language of the speaker. For example - if speaker is speaking in English, provide live transcription in English.

Provide simultaneous live translation of the text. For example - provide live translation in Japanese.


I have an AI model to achieve steps 2 and 3 above. However, I don't know how to implement step 1 i.e. how to build a Teams plugin that could run my AI model in real time.
I have been exploring Microsoft Teams developer documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/mstdd-landing) but there is so much to it and I am kind of lost.
For now, I am trying to create a real-time media bot using Microsoft Azure. This is still in progress -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/real-time-media-concepts
https://dev.botframework.com/bots/new
It would be great if someone could share development experience as to how to go about building a Teams plugin for real-time voice translation. Thank you.

please refer the below sample-https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/master/Samples/V1.0Samples/LocalMediaSamples/PolicyRecordingBot

Hi @Sayali-MSFT, thanks for sharing this sample. However, I am looking for something like this. My Teams app needs to access voice, video, and screen sharing media streams of Teams meeting.  And then, it should be able to modify these streams (for translation work) in Teams meeting itself. Kindly advise if this is even possible.
